# How to process nested delimiters in a same file in unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have a semicolon-separated file.

And one of the fields in the file is pipe-separated.

Example.

```
field-1;field-2;value-1|value-2|value-3;field-4;field-5
```

Here `field-3` is nothing but pipe-separated values.

Now my requirement is that if there are multiple values in `field-3`,

I only have to keep the first value. Discard anything after the first pipe in that field.

i.e., I want to keep only first value in `field-3` as shown below

```
field-1;field-2;value-1;field-4;field-5
```

Can you please tell me how can I achieve this using sed/awk?

Comment: Perhaps you only need a text editor with regex search and replace capability; just search for `|.*;` and replace it with `;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/[|][^;]*//g' YourFile
```

- it remove (replace by nothing) any value after (including) a `|` ( the `[|]` pattern) until it is not a `;` ( the `[^;]` pattern) and for each occurence ( the `g` option)
- Assuming `|` is only a separator and not part of a filed value (like in string)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ x='field-1;field-2;value-1|value-2|value-3;field-4;field-5'
$ echo $x | awk -F";" '{gsub(/\|.*/,"",$3);}1' OFS=";"
field-1;field-2;value-1;field-4;field-5
$
```

Comment: you need a loop to treat each field in this case. you could also directly work on $0 adapting the regex

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^;]*;){2}[^|;]*)[^;]*/\1/' file
```

This matches the first three fields and replaces it by the first two fields and the first value in the third field.

Comment: *one of the field in the file * so not only or specificaly the 3th field likie in the sample i imagine